# One template with different sendable Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to use only one template for sending to different sendable Data Extensions with different fields. How can I manage it when I set the user data like this

```
%%[
Var @COUNTRYCODE, @LANGUAGECODE, @SFID, @EMAIL, @FIRSTNAME
```

DE1:

```
Set @LANGUAGECODE = TRIM(Language) 
Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(Country) 
Set @FIRSTNAME = FirstName
Set @SFID = TRIM(Salesforce_ID)
Set @EMAIL = TRIM(EmailAddress)
```

DE2:

```
Set @LANGUAGECODE = TRIM(Lead:Email_Newsletter_language__c) 
Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(Lead:Website_Country__c) 
Set @SFID = Lead:Id
Set @EMAIL = Lead:Email
```

Thanks!

Oliver

---

I now let the Marketing Manager set the name of the Sendable Data Extension over an Additional Email Attribute

%%[ /* Set user date */

Var @COUNTRYCODE, @LANGUAGECODE, @SFID, @EMAIL, @VERSION, @DataExtension

SET @VERSION = _DataSourceName
Set @DataExtension = "%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%"

IF INDEXOF(@VERSION, @DataExtension) > 0 THEN
  Set @LANGUAGECODE = LOWERCASE(TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Language")))
  Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Country"))
  Set @SFID = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Salesforce_ID"))
  Set @EMAIL = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("EmailAddress"))
ELSE
  Set @LANGUAGECODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Email_Newsletter_language__c")) 
  Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Website_Country__c")) 
  Set @SFID = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Id")
  Set @EMAIL = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Email")
ENDIF
]%%

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How are you sending your emails? Manually, by triggered send or by automation?

Comment: DE1 are the Newsletter Subscribers. We send to them manually. DE2 is a Salesforce Data Event from Journey Builder. The Email is triggered automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the rest of the content outside of the AMPScript variable setting is the same and that the newsletter DE (DE1) will always be the same or the name will be similar enough, what you could do is set a variable based on `%%_DataSourceName%%` [Personalization String](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) to differentiate between the setting of your vars.

For example:

```
%%[
SET @Version = AttributeValue(_DataSourceName)

IF INDEXOF(@Version, "Newsletter") > 0 THEN
/* This is assuming that Newsletter will appear in DE1's name */

Set @LANGUAGECODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Language")) 
Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Country")) 
Set @FIRSTNAME = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("FirstName")
Set @SFID = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Salesforce_ID"))
Set @EMAIL = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("EmailAddress")) 

ELSE
/* it is safer to just have the trigger as an else statement, rather than a second if */

Set @LANGUAGECODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Email_Newsletter_language__c")) 
Set @COUNTRYCODE = TRIM(ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Website_Country__c")) 
Set @SFID = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Id")
Set @EMAIL = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Lead:Email")

ENDIF
]%%
```

By setting the name of the DE to `@Version`, you are able to do a 'Contains' via IndexOf() to search for a naming convention you use for the newsletter to differentiate how each field is set.

I wrapped each inside of an ATTRIBUTEVALUE() function to help handle null values - I honestly do not remember if the Salesforce Data fields will work inside of this (I believe they do) so if it throws an error or shows up empty, try removing the attribute value on the non-newsletter version.

Comment: Hi Gortington, thanks for the reply. What can I do when the names of the sendable DEs change.? Thanks

Comment: That is the reason I used IndexOf() instead of equals.  As long as the word 'Newsletter' is used in the DEs name, it will trigger the appropriate condition.  You can replace 'Newsletter' with whatever repetitive unique convention you want though.